# Loading a txt file that has two columns (one is string, and one is an int)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a text file that has two columns: the first column is labeled as the "date" and it is a string value (i.e. '12/31/19', '1/1/20', etc.). The second column is a value (integer type) that corresponds to the date.

When I attempt to use np.loadtxt, I get the error:
 `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12/31/19'`

So I tried to open the file by using Pandas with read_csv. But I ended up getting a table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFjMM.png). I'm trying to separate the two columns from each other and put the values of each column into two separate arrays. Is there another simple method to open a txt file that has values in string format and place them into a list? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the picture you attached, it looks like your columns are separated by tabs.
You need to set the sep argument to "\t" like this:

```
pandas.read_csv('filename', sep='\t')
# OR
numpy.loadtxt('filename', delimiter='\t')
```